# Netbeans doesn't display a git option under team

Tags: git, netbeans, git-clone

I have git and netbeans installed on Ubuntu and I'm trying to follow [these instructions](https://github.com/magefree/mage/wiki/Developer-Getting-Started), specifically *Team -> Git -> Clone*.

However, when I select `Team` on NetBeans my only options are `cvs, mercurial, subversion, local history and create build job`, with no `git` to be seen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The plugin portal's update centres were inactive. Fix by;

1. Navigating to 'Tools' --> 'Plugins' along the top of the IDE.
2. Go to settings, and tick all the update centres.
3. Go to Available Plugins, search for `git` and voila!

Answer (score 3):

Depending on which version of the Netbeans IDE you are using, the git 'plugin' may not be bundled by default.

1. Navigate to 'Tools' --> 'Plugins' along the top of the IDE.
2. Navigate into the 'Installed' tab of the plugins popup window.
3. Search for 'git' in the search box in the upper right of the plugins window.
4. Git may show up as part of the 'Base IDE' 'plugin' or as the separate git plugin, if it does not show up for either then follow the step below.
5. If you have not been able to locate git: navigate to the 'Available Plugins' tab of the plugins window
6. Search for and download this plugin: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/37577/git-versioning-system-support

Note: The plugin linked is the same git plugin that is shipped with NetBeans by default.

Comment: Did I answer your question? If so you may want to mark the reply as an answer

Comment: Nothing comes up when i search for the link or `git`. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm; so nothing is displayed when searching for 'git' under 'base IDE'? Interesting, as to acquire the git plugin I'm not really sure...will research more shortly

Comment: Ah! The plugin portal's update centre's were inactive.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the default shipped plugins tend to "disappear". To find them go to the plugin window -> Installed and mark the "Show details".
Then check git and activate.